# Launching Delayed HTTP Response with Play

Tags: playframework-2.0

I have a .net class which makes a HTTP Request to a controller in play but my controller has to make the request wait and after some time i have to make response to the request . I tried using Promise but can't figure out how to achieve this need help to solve this...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Plz add the version of Play. There are hugh differences between them.

Comment: @Zenklys sorry my play version is 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awaiting is generally not the best idea. What you probably want to do in this instance is create an Akka actor that gets ping'd by the [Scheduler](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.1/scala/scheduler.html) every so often. When it receives that ping message it would check if the condition you're looking for exists and would notify all the actor-refs that registered interest in that event.

When you send a message to an akka actor via the ask pattern, the sender for that message is an actor backing the Future which is fulfilled once that backing actor is sent a message.

Play 2.0 has a simple way of [turning an Akka Future into a Play Promise](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/ScalaAkka). And there you have it, asynchronous programming with Akka and Play!

So in summary, your Actor needs to react to two messages:
RegisterListener
Ping

RegisterListener is the message you send using the ask pattern, The actor will need to retain a reference to the sender of that listener so that it can be notified when the condition is fulfilled.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to do this in Play 1.2.x, you would use the `await` function. For example, to receive a request, wait for 30 seconds, and then respond, you would do

```
public static void delay30() {
    await("30s");
    renderText("a-response");
}
```

You could use any of the render methods, renderText is just an example.

Comment: thanks for your reply but this will not suit in my case because i was expecting an another event to get triggered when that is triggered i have to make the response to this request

Comment: then simply await a promise, or await for 1s, then check for the event and if event has not happened loop back to await

Comment: if you dont mind can you post me a sample code regarding how to await a promoise in a non blocking manner?